# Why are certain protected methods in ViewGroup not overridable and not in the docs?

Tags: java, android, gridview

(For context,) I'm trying to extend GridView to be like ListView and have headers & footers, but `findViewById` is not working. When I look in ListView's source, I find:

```
@Override
protected View findViewTraversal(int id) {
    View v;
    v = super.findViewTraversal(id);
    ...
}
```

And yet Android Studio (and Gradle) tell me that findViewTraversal does not exist, even though it exists in [ViewGroup's source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.findViewTraversal%28int%29) as well, meaning it should be in GridView.

Why am I not able to override this method in my subclass?

Am I missing some part of the Java language, as I thought protected methods were available via inheritance? `findViewTraversal()` also doesn't exist in the Android docs, so it apparently isn't meant to be used, but I don't understand how it *cannot*.

Comment: I tried to find out, but couldn't find a clear answer. You might find help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071720/why-cant-my-subclass-access-a-protected-variable-of-its-superclass-when-its-i) or [here (jls)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)

Comment: Just a comment related to what you're actually attempting to achieve here (*"extend GridView to be like ListView and have headers & footers"*): have you searched around for existing solutions? I'm pretty sure there are. Alternatively, consider using `RecyclerView` with a [`GridLayoutManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) - this would allow you to add headers/footers (by making items span multiple columns) fairly easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (...) it exists in ViewGroup's source as well, meaning it should be in GridView.

Correct, and it is. The reason you don't see it, is because the method is annotated with `@hide`:

```
/**
 * {@hide} <-- !!!
 */
@Override
protected View findViewTraversal(int id) { ... }
```

It's a little hard to tell from your own `ViewGroup` link, but if you look closely at the line numbers, you'll notice a jump. If you now look at the [raw source](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java/?v=source) of that file, it should become more clear. Little side note: you're referencing a *really* old version of `ViewGroup`.

Back to `@hide`: it's [documented here](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags#@hide):

> When applied to a package, class, method or field, @hide removes that node and all of its children from the documentation.

Basically the annotation indicates the method isn't part of the public API and hence should not be exposed as such. In Android Studio, the annotation also has the side effect of preventing the method from showing up (not sure about Eclipse), so you don't 'accidentally' use it.

Now, `ListView` is a special case. It is the *only* `ViewGroup` that actually overrides the `findViewTraversal(int id)` method (not counting `ExpandableListView`, since that extends `ListView`):

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View#findViewById(int)
 * First look in our children, then in any header and footer views that may be scrolled off.
 */
@Override
protected View findViewTraversal(@IdRes int id) { ... }
```

If you look at the source code snippet above, you'll see it overrides the 'hidden' super method and does *not* have the `@hide` annotation. Since it does contain [`(non-Javadoc)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597329/does-non-javadoc-have-a-well-understood-meaning), I can only assume it is intentionally exposed as part of the public API for `ListView`. As such, it is actually listed in the [method documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#findViewTraversal%28int%29), but of course only for this class.

So in short: the method is there, for every `ViewGroup`, but it's (intentionally) not exposed by default. And before anyone asks: yes, you can use reflection to still access/invoke the method, but I wouldn't rely on that. There is a reason the method isn't part of the public API.